# How to disable the functionality of home button in Android mobiles and can we set some other action for home button?

Tags: android-layout, android, android-button

How to disable the functionality of home button in Android mobiles and can we set some other action for home button? can anyone please give me an example on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `onKeyEvent` of your **activity**

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
        // call the desired code.
        // If you want the home key disabled just uncomment the following line
        // return false;

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
```